# Query max and min in a fixed range of time of each day interval POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql

I have a query below to query max and min of day interval in a range of time ( current_date - 2 to current_date - 1). Now, I need to query dayshift and extra shift separately ( dayshift from 5am to 3pm, extra shift will be the remains).

```
select sum(gap) from (

  select to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as day,
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (max(time_stamp) - min(time_stamp))) /3600 as gap

  from group_table_debarker

  where time_stamp >= (current_date - 2)
    and time_stamp <= (current_date - 1)
    and to_char(time_stamp, 'hh:mi') > '03:00'  and to_char(time_stamp, 'hh:mi') < '15:00'
   
  group by to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd')

) as xxx
```

```
select sum(gap) from (

  select to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as day,
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (max(time_stamp) - min(time_stamp))) /3600 as gap

  from group_table_debarker

  where time_stamp >= (current_date - 2)
    and time_stamp <= (current_date - 1)
    and to_char(time_stamp, 'hh:mi') > '03:00'  and to_char(time_stamp, 'hh:mi') < '15:00'
   
  group by to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd')

) as xxx
```

I've tried this but result wasn't expected

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. What is the result you expected?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi AndW, 
So I've figured out how to do it. Thank for your reply. Here is the query:
select sum(gap) from (

  select to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as day,
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (max(time_stamp) - min(time_stamp))) /3600 as gap

  from group_table_debarker

  where time_stamp >= :date_from
   and time_stamp <= :date_to
 and time_stamp::time >= '05:00:00' and time_stamp::time <= '15:00:00'
  group by to_char(time_stamp, 'yyyy/mm/dd')

) as xxx